# Prime ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that $I=(xy-1)$ is prime but not maximal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Prove also that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ has infinitely many prime ideals. I must prove that the quotient Ring is an Integral domain and not a Field. No idea whatsoever. Any help please.

Comment: Showing that the ideal is a prime ideal is possibly best done directly, without worrying about the quotient ring. Proving that it's not maximal is the same: find a bigger proper ideal that contains it.

Comment: If $p(x,y)q(x,y)$ is a multiple of $xy-1$, then $p(x,1/x)q(x,1/x)$ is the zero rational function. It must happen that either $p(x,1/x)$ or $q(x,1/x)$ is the zero rational function. Assume it is $p(x,1/x)$. Divide $p(x,y)$ by $xy-1$ as polynomials in $y$. We get a remainder $r(x)$ that is a rational function in $x$. This rational function must become zero when we put $y=1/x$. Since there are no $y$ in it is must be zero already. Hence $p(x,y)$ is a multiple of $xy-1$. For the second part, all ideals $(x-r,y-1/r)$ contain $xy-1$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen For all it counts it is an answer. I like this location. If you like some other location, no one stops you from writing your own thing anywhere you like.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy It doesn't, though. Your "answer" can't be upvoted or accepted, so this question will stay in the unanswered queue, and it won't be a good target for future duplicate votes. It can't be properly voted on, so it can't be vetted by the community here. And the comment box explicitly says "Avoid answering questions in comments". So there are several reasons why it doesn't count as an answer, and why I personally think it's strange that you like that location. Having someone else copy your comment and put it in an answer post just to have an official answer is also unnecessary work

Comment: @Arthur None of that is my problem.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy True. But I'm trying to tell you, just putting that exact same text one step further down on the page will make this site a better place. Try to keep that in mind for next time. It's even one less button press, so I truly can't see why you wouldn't jump on the oppurtunity.

Comment: @Arthur It is simple. It is a response to those who vote to close perfectly formulated questions just because they try to use this website as a virtual classroom. Since it is not designed to be such, as soon as a question gets an answer all their efforts become useless. If in addition the answer is in the comments they don't even get their satisfaction of downvoting it. So, double pleasure for me.

Comment: I just don’t understand the discussion going on between X